# Splitting a CSV table into SQL Tables with Foreign Keys

Tags: python, sql, oracle

Say I have the following CSV file

**Purchases.csv**

```
+--------+----------+
| Client |   Item   |
+--------+----------+
| Mark   | Computer |
| Mark   | Lamp     |
| John   | Computer |
+--------+----------+
```

What is the best practice, in Python, to split this table into two separate tables and join them in a bridge table using foreign key, i.e.

**Client table**

```
+----------+--------+
| ClientID | Client |
+----------+--------+
|        1 | Mark   |
|        2 | John   |
+----------+--------+
```

**Item table**

```
+--------+----------+
| ItemID |   Item   |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Computer |
|      2 | Lamp     |
+--------+----------+
```

**Item Client Bridge Table**

```
+----------+--------+
| ClientID | ItemID |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |
|        1 |      2 |
|        2 |      1 |
+----------+--------+
```

I should mention here that it possible for records to already exist in the tables, i.e., if the `Client Name` in the CSV already has an assigned ID in the `Client Table`, this ID should be used in the `Bridge table`. This is because I have to do a one-time batch upload of a million line of data, and then insert a few thousands line of data daily.
I have also already created the tables, they are in the database, just empty at the moment

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this in the database (or via database commands in Python).  The data never needs to be loaded into Python.

Load the `purchases.csv` table into a staging table in the database.  Then be sure you have your tables defined:

```
create table clients (
    clientId int generated always as identity primary key,
    client varchar(255)
);

create table items (
    itemId int generated always as identity primary key,
    item varchar(255)
);

create table clientItems (
    clientItemId int generated always as identity primary key,
    clientId int references clients(clientId),
    itemId int references items(itemId)
);
```

Note that the exact syntax for these depends on the database.  Then load the tables:

```
insert into clients (client)
    select distinct s.client 
    from staging s
    where not exists (select 1 from clients c where c.client = s.client);

insert into items (item)
    select distinct s.item
    from staging s
    where not exists (select 1 from items i where i.item = s.item);
```

I'm not sure if you need to take duplicates into account for `ClientItems`:

```
insert into ClientItems (clientId, itemId)
    select c.clientId, i.itemId
    from staging s join
         clients c
         on s.client = c.client join
         items i
         on s.item = i.item;
```

If you need to prevent duplicates here, then:

```
    where not exists (select 1
                      from clientitems ci join
                           clients c
                           on c.clientid = ci.clientid join
                           items i
                           on i.itemid = ci.itemid
                      where c.client = s.client and i.item = s.item
                     );
```

Comment: Wonderful thank you. There is still an issue however. When inserting new data from the staging table, new IDs for the data are generated, even the data already exist. i.e. if I insert the data a first time, everything works. The second time I try to add new data through the staging table and the insert scripts, say John bought a lamp, both John and Lamp now have a new ID, even though they already exist in their respective table. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The last paragraph explains how this will occur once for a million lines and then daily for much less data after that. It also mentions that the tables already exist in the database but are empty. I can ask another question regardless.

Comment: @johnharrisons . . . I see that.  "buried in the fine print", but it is there.